# overloaded operator new and operator delete with three arguments

Tags: c++, oop, visual-c++, operator-overloading

I have the following piece of code

```
void* Class1::operator new(size_t nSize, LPCSTR lpszFileName, int nLine)
{
    return ::operator new[](nSize,lpszFileName,nLine); 
} 
void Class1::operator delete(void *p, LPCSTR lpszFileName, int nLine)
{ 
    ::operator delete[] (p,lpszFileName,nLine); 
}
```

I do not understand `::operator new[](nSize,lpszFileName,nLine)` and `delete[] (p,lpszFileName,nLine)`. There is a global scope operator "`::`" So it is supposed to call C++ operators, but there are no such overloads in C++ specification. Could you explain why is this?

Comment: Even if there is no such standard C++ overload, the code/project you are working on could have defined a global `new(size_t nSize, LPCSTR lpszFileName, int nLine)` function. - have you verified if this is the case ?

Comment: Someone has defined a `void* operator new(size_t, LPCSTR, int);` at global scope, which is perfectly allowed by the standard.

Comment: thank you for your responces

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Holt mentioned, there is a `new` operator defined at global scope, like:

```
void* operator new(size_t, LPCSTR, int);
```

and is resolved via the scope resolution operator. Same goes for the `delete` case.

Comment: Thank you for your clarification and time.